# Arrow keys does not move cursor to the next cell

Tags: excel

Say I have the following excel sheet:

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
    Range("C1").Select
  End If
  If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 3 Then
    Range("E1").Select
  End If

End Sub
```

I have VBA code (above) tha moves the cursor automatically (using `worksheet_change` method) after entering data in the blue and yellow cells (after entering data in blue cell the cursor moves to the yellow cell, and after entering data in yellow cell the cursor moves to the green cell). The problem is when I use arrow key (down key) to move the cursor from green cell (I'm not entering data there, just moving the cursor from there using arrow keys) to the next cell (E2 or F2), **sometimes** it doesn't move there, it jumps to E16 cell.

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: I added the vba code.